# Google cloud logging python script permission error

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-dataflow

Hi I am trying to write a python script that does exactly what the following command does:

gcloud logging read "logName=projects/[project_name]/logs/[id]"

so when i run that command from the cli it does not give me any error, it outputs the logs as expected.

however when i run my python script:

```
import argparse
import datetime  
import os
import sys
from pprint import pprint

from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import logging

assert "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" in os.environ

def main():
    client = logging.Client()
    log_name = 'log_id'
    logger = client.logger(log_name)
    for entry in logger.list_entries():
        print(entry.payload)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the error:
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not have permission

Im not sure what to do here, since the command line runs, i clearly have permission.
any thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where does this script run? Locally? --> Have you set any path on the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable? Did you run `gcloud auth application-default login`. 
On compute engine/appengine/cloudfunction; does the associated service account have the right permission?

Comment: it runs locally in a docker container. I have GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS set as an environment variable in my bashrc file. I have not run gcloud auth application-default login. But if the gcloud logging read "logName=projects/[project_name]/logs/[id]"
 cli command works. Shouldnt the python script run as well? Even after trying gcloud auth application-default login it doesnt run.

Comment: Not necessarly because gcloud may act with your permission and not the permission of the associated service account keyfile. Can you confirm that the service account has the right permission? . Dumb question, on your docker container have you binded a volume that contains your keyfile? e.g -v local/path/to/keyfile.json:/tmp and then define the var accordingly: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/tmp/keyfile.json

Comment: To be sure, just run gcloud auth list to know which account is used. If it is you, then run `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/path/keyfile.json` and run again `gcloud logging read...` to validate you indeed can read with the permission of your service account. (preferably from your container where you run the python script)

Comment: You are right, I cannot read logs with my service accounts permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are trying to read and show your logs from Cloud Logging using Python.

From the error code you got:

> error: google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403

I think this comes from an authentication problem. I would like to share these documents with you: the Python quickstart to write, read, delete, and export log entries [1]; and authentication on GCE instances [2].

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/quickstart-python#linux

[2] https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#using-google-compute-engine